# DynamoDB multi-field index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have some data that is uniquely identified by three values. Imagine a ticket object identified by section, row, and seat number. What is the best way to index a table like that in DynamoDB?

I could create a single field for the index by concatenating section/row/seat into one string. Is that a good practice? Or I could have an arbitrary ID field as the primary index, but I would still need to search for items by section/row/seat using some kind of secondary index.

What is the best practice for DynamoDB indexing in cases like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat two keys is a good solution, i advice you concat section/row and add as Storting key the seat number, or you can find better combination according to your need.

Knowing that according to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions)

> Key Condition Expression
>
> To specify the search criteria, you use a key condition expression—a
>   string that determines the items to be read from the table or index.
>
> You must specify the partition key name and value as an equality
>   condition.
>
> You can optionally provide a second condition for the sort key (if
>   present). The sort key condition must use one of the following
>   comparison operators: <  > ..